# How do I sort the elements of argv in C?

Tags: c, sorting, argv

I am trying to alphabetically sort the elements of argv.

The following line of code is giving me problems:

```
qsort(argv[optind], argc - optind, sizeof(argv[optind]), sort);
```

Specifically, the last argument is giving me trouble, the comparison function, which is given below:

```
int
sort(const void *a, const void * b)
{    
    return(strcmp( (char*)a, (char*)b ));
}
```

At the moment, it compiles fine, but I end up getting a segmentation fault when I run it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, modifying the `argv` array results in undefined behavior. You might mention this to whoever gave you this homework assignment, and might even get extra credit if you can find the citation in the standard (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: Yes, seems like something some platforms could benefit from doing interesting tricks with, so undefined behaviour seems reasonable. On the other hand, the fact that the man page example plays with the array might indicate otherwise. Or we have found ourselves a bug in the man page. :-)

Comment: Well, actually, the assignment isn't to sort the argv array. Basically, the whole program is supposed to count the number of chars, words, and lines of the specified files and print out the results, but in alphabetical order. My program currently counts everything correctly, but I need to find a way to make it print out in alphabetical order so I thought that sorting the argv array would be a good idea since thats where all the filenames are. 
Anyways, after making a few tweaks as suggested by you guys, I can get it to where it prints out the first file and its counts, but... continued below

Comment: then I get a segmentation fault. I used a printf statement to check what the current filename was when I get the segmentation fault and it shows that it is LANG=en_US.UTF-8  which, I have no idea what that is... To make it more clear, I specified the files test1.txt hello.txt abcd.txt in the command line. And using the qsort(), I can get it to where it prints out abcd.txt (alphabetically first) and the counts for it. But then I get a segmentation fault and checking the filename being passed, I see its LANG

Comment: ...continued from above,
I see its LANG=en_US.UTF-8 

If I don't try to sort it, it works perfect, but prints it out in the order it was entered on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument should be `argv+optind`, as this is the address of the first element in the sequence to be sorted.

Comment: Really? Keep in mind that argv is an array or string pointers, so argv[optind] would be pointing to the first string.

Comment: It needs to point to the start of the list, not inside one of the things to be sorted. `&argv[optind]` might be a more intuitive way to see this, depending on how ones mind works.

Comment: Indeed, and then the sort function needs to compare `char **`.

Comment: Yes. Both things are covered by the man page for `qsort()` on http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort .

Answer (score 3):

The man page for `qsort(3)` contains one example, which does exactly what you want. It also explains why:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

Summary: You are missing one level of referencing on the `qsort()` first argument, and missing one level of dereferencing inside the `sort()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the structure of the argv array.

It is structured like this

```
program\0arg1\0argument2\0a3\0\0
```

The qsort function assumes that all elements are the same size, but in this case they are not. You specify the size of `argv[optind]`, but not all elements are that size.

**Edit**:
I was mistaken, you do not pass the string length to qsort, but the length of the pointers. So argv contains an array of pointers. The goal is to sort the pointers.

That means that you pass the array of pointers to qsort, and that the sort function should expect a pointer. Like this:

```
int
sort(const void *a, const void * b)
{
    return(strcmp( *(char**)a, *(char**)b ));
}

qsort(argv+optind, argc - optind, sizeof(argv[optind]), sort);
```

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to sort the elements of argv?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `argv` is an array of pointers. If the string data pointed to by those pointers happens to be structured as in your answer, it's purely an implementation detail of the OS/compiler **you** are using. `argv` should never be accessed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at sorting `argv`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int mycomp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  /* function code removed to prevent homework copy/paste */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  qsort(argv + 1, argc - 1, sizeof *argv, mycomp);
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) printf("i: %d ==> '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

And a sample run of the program

```
$ ./a.out one two three four five six seven
i: 1 ==> 'five'
i: 2 ==> 'four'
i: 3 ==> 'one'
i: 4 ==> 'seven'
i: 5 ==> 'six'
i: 6 ==> 'three'
i: 7 ==> 'two'
```