# const qualifier in qsort compare function

Tags: c, argv, qsort

I have this to sort a string array (`argv` itself) in two ways with qsort. i started with the linux `man 3 qsort` example. There `cmpstringp` is only one line:

```
 /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
    pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
    to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

 return strcmp(*(const char **) p1, *(const char **) p2);
```

I tried to reformulate this and it compiles without warnings only with

`char *const* sp1 = vep1`

i.e. `const` belongs in the middle - it is the `argv` entry (?). At least that is what qsort declaration demands. The above cast from man page seems different and complicated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* vep: void pointer to elements being qsorted 
   sp: string pointer (char **)            */
int 
cmpstringp(const void *vep1, const void *vep2) {

    char *const *sp1 = vep1,
         *const *sp2 = vep2;

    return strcmp(*sp1, *sp2);
}
/* Make char* from void*, and even char    */
int 
cmpchar(const void *p1, const void *p2) {

    const char *cp1 = p1,
               *cp2 = p2;

    char c1 = *cp1,
         c2 = *cp2;

    if (c1 == c2)
        return 0;
    else
        return c1 > c2 ? 1 : -1;
}

/* Sort cmd line args in two ways with qsort */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /* sort chars of each string */
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    qsort(argv[i],                  // base / first  
          strlen(argv[i]), 1,       // n_elems, elem_size
          cmpchar);

    /* sort argv strings 1 to argc-1 */
    qsort(argv + 1,
          argc - 1, sizeof *argv,
          cmpstringp);

    for (int j = 1; j < argc; j++)
        puts(argv[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

The second cmp function `cmpchar` has one extra assignment level. Without there would be just some harmless stars like `if (*cp1 == *cp2)`.

[How do I sort the elements of argv in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707051/how-do-i-sort-the-elements-of-argv-in-c) has a solution like man page, with a cast directly in `strcmp()`.

But isn't my cast-free approach more correct? I got warnings until I put the `const` where it belongs.

Comment: `cp1` and `sp1` are not void pointers.

Comment: free of `explicit casts`

Comment: @user3386109, you are correct. The OP's solution to their argument impedance problem, deploys implicit conversion to an intermediary, without the use of any cast operators.  The effect in terms of code generation and quality is arguably NIL, but I am too tired to argue the finer points any further.

Answer (score 3):

The `const` in the *middle* of `char *const *sp1 = vep1` means that whatever is designated by `*sp1` is `const`. This is required because the `const void *` says that the memory directly pointed to by the pointer is supposed to be `const`.

You're right in that `const void *` is not assignable to `const char **` without a cast because it would not be const correct. I personally try to avoid casts as much as is meaningfully possible, and therefore would prefer your code over the one that uses casts.

However It would be somewhat more correct to use `const char *const *sp1`, because there is no reason why `cmpstringp` shouldn't *actually* work for `const char **` too!

Comment: For the record, I am in full agreement, that avoiding explicit casts is a best practice.

Comment: Re “However It would be somewhat more correct to use const char *const *sp1”: This makes the behavior undefined. If `qsort` is passed a `char **` and then the comparison routine defines `const char * const *sp1 = vep1` and uses `*sp1`, it accesses the `char *` that `sp1` points to with an lvalue of type `const char *`. This is not any of the cases allowed by the aliasing rules in 6.5 7: They are not compatible, the latter is not a qualified version of a type compatible with the former, they are not signed/unsigned pairs, the latter is not an aggregate or union, and it is not a character type.

Comment: (`char *` and `const char *` are not compatible per C 2018 6.7.6.1 2: “For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types,” and 6.7.3 11: “For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type…”)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, even though I don't fully understand all this in the specs. Illustration: with `const char **argv` in main, there is a discarding-const warning because of qsort's first arg (base), which wants `void *`.  The sorting works: the chars have not been modified, only moved around! Formally. Would make more sense with whole structs. Qsort actually wants base as `void *` and the compar-args as `const void *`. Makes sense because of the call hierarchy. Only seems both  pedantic and paradoxical.

Comment: @BraCas: `main` should not be declared with `const char *argv[]`. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is correct.

Comment: But after duplicating the argv array and the strings this would be a very realistic situation. Then you have to give qsort the license to modify with a `(void *)` cast or handle the discarding const warning otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Reordered and aligned it becomes more clear what is converted and what is *conserved* from right to left:

```
   int cmpstringp(void const *vep1, const void *vep2) {
    
                char * const *sp1    = vep1, ...
```

The `const` is copied, and the "to void" is replaced by "to pointer (to char). It does not even have to be a pointer (e.g. a struct). If, then I doubt this const-ness can be spread onto all references, just because a "compare" function is not supposed to modify at all. It may modify all objects, but not the ones being sorted.

This is all very interesting but logically complicated. Like having a row of boxes with letters inside. First you sort the letters inside each box according to themselves (not touching the boxes), then you sort the boxes according to the letters (but not touching them, the letters).

Thank you for comments and answer.

---

**6.5.16.1  Simple assignment** probably handles this case.

3 bullets for **pointer assignment** seem to demand:

- compatible types, or one is void
- left side has all the qualifiers of the right side.
- null pointer on the right is no problem